V vs no V in Python interpreter?
If I have defined a Python virtual environment and set it as my Python interpreter in PyCharm, what's the difference between interpreters marked with a V and those that aren't? Both are (actually) virtual environments that I have already set up, and both seem to manage packages correctly both inside the IDE and at the command line.
But — does PyCharm actually do differently if a project's Python interpreter is marked with a V?
